# Google GeoChart now saying "loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported BUT solution assumes data is ready

Tags: google-visualization

After years of showing GeoCharts on my website without a callback, the API is now returning that error.

In searching for a solution, none of the examples fit my use case.  All the examples -- and the Google documentation -- assumes my data is ready when the API is loaded.  Once the API is loaded, the callback is called and that's it.  In my case, data is not ready for sometime after the API is loaded (maybe 10 seconds later) and can change every few hours without a page load.  The examples show hard-coded values (available, obviously at page load time) and other than that, it's not clear how to update the chart except add a event to respond to user clicks.

Sorry if I'm overlooking something!  I've spent hours....  Website basically work, it's just that error message.

I tried adding a call back.